# A good reference for the wave front set

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, schwartz-distributions, reference-request

Hello,

I am wondering whether anyone know some good references for the theory of wave front set, microlocal analysis? I have some basic knowledge of distribution theory at the level of the  Rudin's functional analysis (the first part). As for PDE theory, I learned this topic mainly by Folland's "Introduction to Partial Differential Equations".

When I learned the distribution theory, the book by Strichartz gave me many intuition and helped me 
a lot. I am wondering whether there is a similar book to introduce the theory of wave front set, microlocal analysis?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The standard reference is, of course, Lars Hormander, *Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators*, vols 1-4. Unfortunately I wouldn't say it is a "similar book" to the book of Strichartz. 

Comment: @Willie Wong, Hormander's books seem too difficult. If there is no counter part of Strichartz, I will have to read them... Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm really out of date with this stuff, but in my day the books I looked at were Treves (Introduction to Pseudodifferential and Fourier Integral Operators) and stuff written by Michael Taylor. Also really nice is Geometric Asymptotics by Guillemin and Sternberg.

Comment: Another book that I used was by Chazarain and Piriou: http://books.google.com/books?id=Gh9XeWnOzagC&lpg=PP1&ots=eSuR3gcEs5&dq=chazarain-piriou&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Actually, I think vol 1 of Hormander is about the most lucid book I have ever seen (and I am no analyst).

Comment: Igor, it's been a long time since I looked at Hormander's book, so I don't remember my reaction to it. But, after a quick look at the table of content, I think you're probably right.

Comment: Some references in microlocal analysis are listed in http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/microlocal%20analysis

Comment: @Zoran, Thank you for the reference. :-)

Comment: @Prof. Yang, Thank you for your references. The book Geometric Asymptotics looks very interesting. :-)

Comment: The most elementary introduction that I know is the book "Elementary Introduction to the Theory of Pseudodifferential Operaotors" by Xavier Saint Raymond, it has only 100 pages and assumes basic knowledge of real analysis only.

Comment: @Tim van Beek. Thank you very much for this reference. I will have a look. :-)

Comment: You can look at the last part of Friedlander and Joshi's book "Introduction to the Theory of Distributions".  The latest edition has stuff on the wavefront set.  The goal of their book is to prepare you to look in Hörmander for more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many references at various levels of difficulty; it also depends on what aspects are you interested in. I cite out of memory, so beware of inaccuracies (which can be corrected according to your needs).

A very good reference is Hormander I (The theory of linear partial diff. op), chapter VIII. The emphasis there is on the $C^\infty$ theory, with Hormander's own definition of WF as a limit. You cutoff the function near a point, Fourier transform it, then examine in which directions the Fourier transform decays fast and in which ones it does not. These last directions stabilize as the cutoff support tends to the point, and what remains is the WF set at the point. Further results, written in an even denser style, are contained in Michael Taylor's book on Pseudodifferential Operators. More recently, the concept has been generalized to include directions of Sobolev regularity and has found applications in nonlinear equations; there results are scattered in a number of papers (JM Bony wrote some papers on this).

There are other points of view; an important one is the analytic wave front set. Here the accent is more on the algebraic aspects, since the set of all solutions to an equation or system of PDEs is studied as a whole. Here the best references are japanese, a good starting point being Akira Kaneko's book on hyperfunction theory, and continuing with the works of Kashiwara (including a book), Sato, Schapira.

EDIT: I understand that an easier introduction would be helpful. You should try with section II.B of Alinhac-Gerard Operateurs pseudodifferentiels et Theoreme de Nash-Moser. It's very readable (assuming you read french :)

Comment: @Prof. Piero D'Ancona, thank you very much. These references are very useful. I will have a look. :-)

Comment: Alinhac-Gerard has been translated in GSM 82.

Comment: @Timur, Thank you. :-) I will have a look of the translated version.

Comment: For convenience of references, here is the book by Alinhac-Gerard: http://books.google.ch/books?id=WUCXXRSl_6kC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Alinhac-Gerard&source=bl&ots=d_DDxp47CX&sig=TqrrX_n3Ez5HfCvY85R6f9Yc8Nw&hl=en&ei=r2z5TMzMEpPP4gb6rsGfAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false